# GAE 1.9.18 deploying locally gets ClassCastException ApiProxyLocalImpl cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocal

Tags: google-app-engine

I've upgraded to SDK 1.9.14 -> 1.9.18 and now when I deploy my local server I get an error.

```
Initializing App Engine server
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:53 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\killesk\workspace\EurekaAppServer\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:53 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\killesk\workspace\EurekaAppServer\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:53 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\killesk\.eclipse\org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0_1751554412_win32_win32_x86_64\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.9.18\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties' from 'C:\Users\killesk\workspace\EurekaAppServer\war\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:53 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:54 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: jetty-6.1.x
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:56 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed _ah_ServeBlobFilter: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocal
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:56 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@532dd8a3{/,C:\Users\killesk\workspace\EurekaAppServer\war}
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocal
    at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.init(ServeBlobFilter.java:55)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:255)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:288)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)

Mar 25, 2015 9:39:56 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8888
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:56 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: Module instance default is running at http://localhost:8888/
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:56 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule startup
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
Mar 25, 2015 9:39:56 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl doStart
INFO: Dev App Server is now running
[WARN] No startup URLs supplied and no plausible ones found -- use -startupUrl
```

Here is my class path file for my project:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="test"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-agent.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-agentimpl.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.18.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-labs-1.9.18.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-labs.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints-deps.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-endpoints.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.18.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/json_simple-1.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api-stubs.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-api.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/google_sql.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="war/WEB-INF/lib/appengine-testing.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/mockito-all-1.9.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Here is what's in my WEN-INF lib folder:

```
12/02/2015  11:42             3,648 appengine-agent.jar
12/02/2015  11:42           361,779 appengine-agentimpl.jar
24/03/2015  17:33        16,697,613 appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.18.jar
12/02/2015  11:42        13,595,591 appengine-api-labs-1.9.18.jar
24/03/2015  17:33        13,595,591 appengine-api-labs.jar
12/02/2015  11:42         6,206,715 appengine-api-stubs.jar
12/02/2015  11:42        16,697,613 appengine-api.jar
24/03/2015  17:33            20,822 appengine-endpoints-deps.jar
24/03/2015  17:33         2,038,124 appengine-endpoints.jar
24/03/2015  17:33             7,111 appengine-jsr107cache-1.9.18.jar
12/02/2015  11:42         4,802,606 appengine-testing.jar
24/03/2015  17:33            46,022 asm-4.0.jar
21/01/2015  13:24           185,140 commons-io-2.4.jar
24/03/2015  17:33           317,326 datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.3.jar
24/03/2015  17:33           254,559 datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.3.jar
24/03/2015  17:33           343,590 datanucleus-appengine-2.1.2.jar
24/03/2015  17:33         1,730,830 datanucleus-core-3.1.3.jar
24/03/2015  17:33           114,863 geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.0.jar
12/02/2015  11:42         6,802,416 google_sql.jar
24/03/2015  17:32         9,230,861 gwt-servlet.jar
24/03/2015  17:33           201,124 jdo-api-3.0.1.jar
09/03/2015  13:08            16,046 json_simple-1.1.jar
24/03/2015  17:33             8,082 jsr107cache-1.1.jar
24/03/2015  17:33            15,071 jta-1.1.jar
23/09/2014  06:15           489,883 log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

This is my class path:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
C:\gradle-1.12\bin;
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;
C:\lib\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;
C:\lib\commons-fileupload;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\sdk\platform-tools\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\sdk\tools\;
C:\lib\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin\;
C:\MinGW\bin\;
C:\cygwin64\bin\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\sdk\platform-tools\;
C:\lib\jaybird-2.2.7\;
C:\lib\jaybird-2.2.7\lib\
```

And here is my run arguments:
[image]

[image]

If you require more information please ask. I've been stumped on this for a day now at least. Can anyone spot why my local server fails to start?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here, the comment at the bottom:

> http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/roo/111675-gwt-example-broken-when-using-gae

```
I get it work by removing three jars file from the target folder: 
appengine-api-labs
appengine-api-stubs
appengine-testing

According to this link:
http://www.mail-archive.com/google-a.../msg18983.html
```

Right so, I removed 4 jars from the WEB-INF\lib folder:

1. appengine-api-labs
2. appengine-api-stubs
3. appengine-testing
4. appengine-api-labs-1.9.18.jar

I then removed the above 4 jars from my project classpath, and added only 3 jars from the SDK folder to the project classpath:

1. C:\lib\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\lib\impl\appengine-api-labs
2. C:\lib\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\lib\impl\appengine-api-stubs
3. C:\lib\appengine-java-sdk-1.9.18\lib\testing\appengine-testing

and BOOM!!! local server runs:)